# Rails has_one, :as => (best practice)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Say a model has two children models of the same type, but two different classifications, for example a `Shop` has two `ShippingOptions`, but one is international and one local

In other words, you *know* it will *always* have exactly two, one international and one local,

is it good practice, or even possible to do the following:

shop.rb

```
has_one :shipping_option, :as => :international_shipping_option
has_one :shipping_option, :as => :local_shipping_option
```

Otherwise, how should this be handled (best practice)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It's completely normal to do that, but you've chosen the wrong syntax.

You're after a `belongs_to`, and you need to use your "as" option as the name of the association, and specify an explicit class name:

```
belongs_to :international_shipping_option, class_name: 'ShippingOption'
belongs_to :local_shipping_option, class_name: 'ShippingOption'
```

The name of the association maps to the foreign key, so you should have two columns called `international_shipping_option_id` and a `local_shipping_option_id` in your `shop` table.

Comment: And then `has_one :shop` in shipping_option.rb ?

Comment: You probably don't need anything in `shipping_option.rb`. You only need to specify both sides of the association if you intend to *use* both sides. Do you ever plan to look up a shipping option, and find all shops that used that shipping option? If so, you probably want a `has_many :shops`.

Comment: A shipping option will only be associated with 1 shop.. and I need to be able to query which shop that is, from the shipping option

Comment: Then yes, `has_one :shop` in your `ShippingOption` class.